# How can you tell if a distribution is normal based on summary statistics?

Tags: statistics

[image]

Because the count is less than 20, how can I evaluate if this is a normal distribution?

If the count is greater than 30 then I can use the CLT to justify that its a normal distribution right? Or is that only for a sampling distribution and does it not apply to specific sample?

Comment: No you cannot.  An infinite number of distributions can give the same mean, standard deviation, minimum, maximum, etc.

Comment: thank you. so does the CLT not apply even when the sample is greater than 30?

Comment: There is nothing magic about $30$... so *no*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First, whether the data were sampled from a normal
population. Second, why do you care whether the data are normal.

(1) @DavidG.Stork is correct that there is no way to know for sure from such a
data summary whether this is a sample from a normal population. There are
several indications that the data may be normal---even though it would be
nice to know the lower and upper quartiles. (a) Indication of symmetry:
the mean is about halfway between the min and max. (b) Range is about four
times the standard deviation, which is reasonable for a normal sample of
size 20. [See simulation below.]

(2) If you're wondering whether it's OK to use t methods (confidence interval
or test), then it may be OK. There really is nothing magic about $n = 30.$

As a practical matter, if you have *only* these summary statistics, then you could compute a t
confidence interval or do a t test to see if population mean is consistent with $\mu = 60.$ (I'm not saying it is a *good idea* to do that without seeing the 20 observations, but you *could* do it.) But without the actual data, you wouldn't be able to do any of the most common nonparametric alternative procedures.

---

*Simulation:* It is not unusual for a sample from a normal distribution with
mean 40 and standard deviation 8 to have a range about 30, nor for the ratio
of range to SD to be about 4.

```
set.seed(2020)
m = 10^5;  n = 20;  rng = sd = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  x = rnorm(n, 60, 8)
  sd[i] = sd(x)
  rng[i] = diff(range(x))  }
mean(sd);  mean(rng)
[1] 7.892796
[1] 29.86191
mean(rng/sd)
[1] 3.783623
```